# Should echoing a PHP $_GET variable remove + character?

Tags: php, url

I have a URL string like https://example.com/path/?welcome_screen=1&email_address=something+else@example.com

In PHP, I call `<?php echo $_GET['email_address']; ?>`

Which produces `something else@example.com`

Specifically, a space instead of the + in the email address.

1. Is this expected?
2. If so, is there a way to prevent this from happening in the `echo` code above?
3. Or should it be handled when collecting the email address somehow?

Comment: The `$_GET` is auto decoded so the `+` becomes the space. If you want the `+` you should URL encode it. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php... half way down, `The GET variables are passed through urldecode().`

Comment: Also `echo $_GET...` is open to XSS injections.

Comment: I would just note to the SO devs, if "This question already has answers..." then they should appear when suggesting that the question I was writing might have answers. Those presented at that time were absolutely obscure. :P Otherwise, yinz rock.

Comment: @Nathan if you want some attention for that observation you should consider starting a post on Meta Stackoverflow about it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, `+` is one way to represent a space character in a URL. PHP [automatically URL-decodes the value when it creates the `$_GET` data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and converts it to a space, as it assumes that's what the value is supposed to represent in the raw URL.
2. No, it's too late by then.
3. Yes, you should [URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the value before including it in the URL, so that the `+` is not treated as a special character. If PHP is generating the URL, you'd use the [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function. Most other programming languages have equivalent built-in functions.

Comment: In javascript, this is done like so : `encodeURI('something else@example.com')`, which gives : `'something%20else@example.com'`